# Proguard with google-play-services

Tags: android, apk, proguard, google-play-services

I have an Android project (target=Google APIs:17).
I'm using Proguard and everything works just fine until I added google-play-services library as a dependency. 
Now I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.InstructionOffsetValue]
at proguard.evaluation.value.Value.referenceValue(Value.java:97)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.isPoppingSimpleEnum(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:530)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.isPoppingSimpleEnum(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:520)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.visitVariableInstruction(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:229)
at proguard.classfile.instruction.VariableInstruction.accept(VariableInstruction.java:306)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.visitCodeAttribute(SimpleEnumUseSimplifier.java:131)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:373)
at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:483)
```

I tried everything and nothing happened :(

Here is my proguard cfg file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*


-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.Maps

-keepclassmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class **.R$*

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.tjeannin.apprate.** {
   *;
}


-dump class_files.txt 
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt 

-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.AviaryEffect
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.media.ExifInterfaceWrapper
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.moa.Moa
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.moa.MoaResult
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.moa.MoaHD
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.filters.NativeFilterProxy
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.utils.CameraUtils
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.gl.GLUtils

-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.opengl.AviaryGLSurfaceView
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.widget.ScrollerRunnable
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.library.services.BaseContextService
-keep class it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.easing.Easing
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.library.external.tracking.TrackerFactory
-keep class com.aviary.android.feather.library.tracking.AbstractTracker

-keep interface com.aviary.android.feather.library.services.IAviaryController
-keep interface com.aviary.android.feather.headless.filters.IFilter
-keep interface com.aviary.android.feather.widget.ScrollerRunnable$ScrollableView

-keep class * extends com.aviary.android.feather.library.tracking.AbstractTracker
-keep class * extends com.aviary.android.feather.headless.filters.IFilter
-keep class * extends com.aviary.android.feather.headless.filters.INativeFilter
-keep class * implements com.aviary.android.feather.library.services.IAviaryController
-keep class * extends com.aviary.android.feather.library.services.BaseContextService
-keep class * implements com.aviary.android.feather.widget.ScrollerRunnable$ScrollableView { *; }
-keep class * implements java.lang.Runnable

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    protected <init>( com.aviary.android.feather.library.services.BaseContextService );
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>( com.aviary.android.feather.library.services.IAviaryController );
}

-keepclassmembers class com.aviary.android.feather.library.tracking.AbstractTracker { *; }

-keepclassmembers interface it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.easing.Easing { *; }

-keepclassmembers class com.aviary.android.feather.library.external.tracking.TrackerFactory { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * implements it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.easing.Easing { *; }

# This class should not be obfuscated at all
-keepclassmembers class com.aviary.android.feather.headless.moa.MoaResult {
    public java.lang.String inputString;
    public android.graphics.Bitmap inputBitmap;
    public java.lang.String outputString;
    public android.graphics.Bitmap outputBitmap;
    public volatile int active;
    public void cancel();
    public synchronized void execute();
}

# Keep all classes with a native method

-keepclassmembers class * {
   public static native <methods>;
   private static native <methods>;
   static native <methods>;
   private native <methods>;
   native <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Signature
```

Please help me with this one,

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you use Android Studio, ProGuard directives are included

> Note: ProGuard directives are included in the Play services client libraries to preserve the required classes. The Android Plugin for Gradle automatically appends ProGuard configuration files in an AAR (Android ARchive) package and appends that package to your ProGuard configuration. During project creation, Android Studio automatically creates the ProGuard configuration files and build.gradle properties for ProGuard use. To use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable the ProGuard setting in your build.gradle buildTypes. For more information, see the ProGuard topic.

Reference: [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: What exactly do I have to do? It seems the text says proguard rules are setup automatically via gradle, but that does not happen for me?

Comment: well it still fails https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329060/9766649 until I manually do `-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}`

Answer (score 8):

You did not include the Google Play Service Proguard exceptions:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard

Comment: How exactly do I add this exceptions? It seems it only says that the exceptions are added autmatically?

Comment: The answer is from 2014. At that time, using Eclipse you had to add the exceptions yourself. Today that's not the case & the exception should be added automatically when merging modules & dependencies. In addition Android Studio create a proguard configuration file in every new module called "proguard-rules.pro". You can add manual exceptions there.

Comment: so issue still happens https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329060/9766649 so 1-2 weeks ago everything was fine