# Android build release failed with Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 213 (proguard issue)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My project is built fine with debug build variant, but with release variant Android Studio throws:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 213

[image]

[image]

What could be the issue?

If I set `minifyEnabled false` in build gradle for release build variant then it is being built ok, but it's not good

**Update**

I tried to add to `proguard-rules.pro` `-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}`

And it builds but I don't like this solution, I don't want to keep everything of that `com.google.android.gms`...

Any good solution?

p.s. I use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` it root build.gradle as a dependency

**Update 2**

Now it started to throw `Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease'.`

Multi Dex library is used of course (I'm targeting Android API 14+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by updating to Android Studio 3.4 RC 2 which uses **R8** by default instead of **Proguard**

Now build variant with `minifyEnabled true` works fine

Seems **R8** can be used with Stable AS 3.3 too but it needs some configuration: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html